# Fake small caps with UTF-8 on pdfTeX

Tags: pdftex, small-caps, arev

I am using arev package for a scientific LaTeX article (compiling using pfdlatex) and would like to use small caps for certrain proper names. On the internet I found a code

```
\def\fauxschelper#1#2\relax{%
    \ifnum`#1>``\ifnum`#1<`\{\scalebox{.87}[.79]{\uppercase{#1}}\else#1\fi\else#1\fi%
    \ifx\relax#2\relax\else\fauxschelper#2\relax\fi}
\newcommand\fauxsc[1]{\fauxschelper#1\relax\relax}
```

which looks kind of nice, but doesn’t work when I try to use unicode characters with UTF-8 encoding. It seems to try to interpret the unicode characters byte-wise rather than character-wise.

Since I need especially umlauts to work properly, I tried something else using the etoolbox package:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

% GENERAL STUFF - ENCODING, LANGUAGE
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

% GENERAL STUFF - FONT
\usepackage{arev}

% GENERAL STUFF - GRAPHICS
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% DEPENDS ON GRAPHICX PACKAGE (WHICH CAN BE USEPACKAGE'd LATER)
% ESSENTIALLY YOU JUST NEED TO TAKE A LOOK WHETHER \uppercase{\next} IS THE SAME AS \next. Use scalebox on the uppercase'd letter if not.
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\fsc}[1]{%
    \@tfor\next:=#1\do{%
        \edef\temp@up{\uppercase{\next}}%
        \ifdefstrequal{\temp@up}{\next}{\next}{\scalebox{.87}[.79]{\uppercase{\next}}}%
    }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
The \fsc{Schr{ö}dinger} equation is \dots
\end{document}
```

This produces the text „Schrödinger“, where each letter is in the case specified in the \fsc command and scaled with a \scalebox. The expected result would be that the comparison yields true if a character is equal to its uppercase form (so if it represents an uppercase letter) and false otherwise, so that it yields an uppercase unscaled letter S and uppercase scaled letters CHRÖDINGER.

I suppose my problem has something to do with the order in which TeX evaluates commands, but since I’m very new to programming LaTeX macros, I have no idea how to fix this.

What would also be nice is a way of coding the command to prevent having to write multi-byte characters in braces.

Comment: `\uppercase` is not expandable. You can use `\tl_upper_case:n` from `expl3`.

Comment: do you have to use utf8? If you used latin1 then all (supported) characters are single byte and things are a lot easier.

Comment: I don’t need need to use UTF-8, but I’ve used it in all other files so far and I would like to stick with it, because I’m often using characters that are not contained in Latin1 and would have to be paraphrased otherwise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Highly inefficient and no real substitute for true small caps (my suggestion is to avoid faking small caps at all costs). All common accents are covered, others can be added.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

% GENERAL STUFF - ENCODING, LANGUAGE
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

% GENERAL STUFF - FONT
\usepackage{arev}

% GENERAL STUFF - GRAPHICS
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\fsc}{m}
 {
  \toshiki_fsc:n { #1 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l_toshiki_input_tl

\cs_set_eq:Nc \toshiki_tl_set_protecteded_x:Nn { protected@edef }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \toshiki_fsc:n
 {
  \toshiki_tl_set_protecteded_x:Nn \l_toshiki_input_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { ([a-z]+) } { \c{toshiki_fake_sc:n}\cB\{\1\cE\} } \l_toshiki_input_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { (\c{[r"'`^]})\c{toshiki_fake_sc:n}\cB. }
                         { \c{toshiki_fake_sc:n}\cB\{\1 } \l_toshiki_input_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { (\c{ae|oe|ss}) } { \c{toshiki_fake_sc:n}\cB\{\1\cE\} } \l_toshiki_input_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_toshiki_input_tl
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \toshiki_fake_sc:n
 {
  \scalebox{.87}[.79]{ \MakeUppercase{#1} }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

The \fsc{Schr{ö}dinger} equation is \dots

\fsc{Hôpital} \fsc{Ångström} \fsc{ångström} \fsc{ŒœÆæß}

\fsc{Some Wörds To Be In Småll Cáps}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My concern is not so much with efficiency of the process and more about a convienient solution that yields a good-looking final result. Compile time is through the roof already, because I include a lot of graphics and some chemical formulae. (I use chemfig, which is really cool, but also _very_ slow.)

Comment: @Toshiki It is *not* good looking, sorry. But it just depends on the faked small caps.

Comment: @Toshiki There is a library in the `TikZ` universe `\usetikzlibrary{external} ` which precompiles the figures. This way I reduces my (very long) compile time to a few seconds, because it just included the precompiled figures. Just do a big compile when you edit your figures. It isn't directly applicable here, but maybe it helps you anyway :-).

Answer (score 3):

An approximation. If unicode characters appear not in minuscules, it doesn't work correctly. May be there's a solution with `\str_case:nnF` but you should do it manually, or just use LuaTeX (or XeTeX).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{arev}

\usepackage{xparse} % loads expl3
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcase} % to get \MakeTextUppercase

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \fsc { m } { \toshiki_fsc:n { #1 } }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \toshiki_fsc:n #1
 {
  \tl_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \str_if_eq:eeTF { ##1 } { \text_uppercase:n { ##1 } }
     { ##1 }
     { \scalebox{.87}[.79]{ \toshiki_fsc_aux:n { ##1 } } }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \toshiki_fsc_aux:n #1 { \MakeTextUppercase { #1 } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
The \fsc{Schr{ö}dinger} equation is\dots\ \fsc{Schr{Ö}dinger} doesn't work, though\dots
\end{document}
```

but if you redefine `\toshiki_fsc_aux:n` with

```
\cs_new_protected:Npn \toshiki_fsc_aux:n #1
 {
  \str_case:nnTF { #1 }
   {
    {Ö}{}
    {Á}{}
    % etc.
   }
   { #1 }
   { \scalebox{.87}[.79]{ \MakeTextUppercase { #1 } } }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \toshiki_fsc_aux:n #1
 {
  \tl_if_in:nnTF { ÖÁ } { #1 }
   { #1 }
   { \scalebox{.87}[.79]{ \MakeTextUppercase { #1 } } }
 }
```

then it does work, but you have to add the characters manually.

By the way, this is a messy solution, with patches here and there…

Answer (score 3):

If you need this "fake small caps" only for names and only for single words (note that spaces don't work in your solution) then you can prepare a simple macro `\fcs` which keeps the first letter unchanged and the rest is uppercased and scaled.

```
\def\fsc#1{\fscA#1\relax}
\def\fscA#1#2\relax{#1\scalebox{.87}[.79]{\uppercase{#2}}}

test: \fsc{Schrödinger} equation.
```

If the first letter is accented then you must to enclose it into braces because LaTeX treats badly with UTF-8 codes (if you are using csplain then this problem doesn't occur).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest another solution of the problem of processing the macro argument "character per character" when UTF-8 code and `\usepackage{inputenc}` is used. You can compare the simplicity of mine solution with others presented here.

Suppose, that you have set `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`. Then the UTF-8 codes expand to simple tokens with respect to T1 encoding and the `\lccode` are set to T1 encoding too. Then you can do this:

```
\def\fsc#1{\edef\tmp{#1}\expandafter\fscA\tmp\relax}
\def\fscA#1{%
   \ifx#1\relax \else
      \ifnum\lccode`#1=`#1 (small:\char\uccode`#1)\else (cap:#1)\fi
      \expandafter\fscA
\fi
}

A test: \fsc{Schrödinger} equation.
```

Comment: Well, mine also copes with spaces (yours doesn't) and also accepts `\fsc{Abc \emph{def}}`.

Comment: And with OT1 you're doomed, of course.